# Reputation points are not centered for root site

Tags: bug, reputation, design, stackexchange.com, achievements-dialog

If you try to look at the achievements dialog on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) you can see that reputation points are not centered relatively icons:

> [image: root]

For any other site (even for [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)) they are centered:

> [image: noroot]